# How to get rid of GRUB2 error "failure reading sector 0xb30 from `fd0'" on HP server

Tags: hp-proliant, grub2

When I boot into my HP ProLiant DL120 G7 server's GRUB2 rescue shell, I get the following output:

```
error: failure reading sector 0xb30 from `fd0'.
error: failure reading sector 0x0 from `fd0'.
error: failure reading sector 0xb30 from `fd1'.
error: file `/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.
Entering rescue mode...
```

Disregard the `error: file ... not found.`, that is because my GRUB files are not correctly installed. But these other errors make using the shell a pain, they also clutter `ls`:

```
grub rescue> ls                                                                 
(hd0) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1) (hd1) (hd1,gpt2) (hd1,gpt1) (lvm/vg0-root0) (md/root
0) (fd0) (fd1) error: failure reading sector 0xb30 from `fd0'.
error: failure reading sector 0x0 from `fd0'.
error: failure reading sector 0xb30 from `fd1'.
```

What is going on, and how can I get rid of these `failure reading sector` messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fd0` and `fd1` are floppy drives.

The server has an option in the BIOS to emulate virtual floppy drives that can be configured via the server's iLO.

You can simply disable these floppy drives in the BIOS if you don't need them, via the BIOS menu structure:

```
Advanced Options
  Advanced System ROM Options
    Virtual Install Disk
      Disabled
```

See also the [HP ROM-Based Setup Utility User Guide](https://h20628.www2.hp.com/km-ext/kmcsdirect/emr_na-c00191707-19.pdf), section `Virtual Install Disk` page 109.